# Rails 4 - Parse URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, uri

I'm parsing a URL in my Rails application. I want to get the domain `example.com` stripped of any protocol, subdomain, directories, etc.

My method:

```
def clean_host(url)
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  return uri
end
```

What I actually get for `example.com/` is:

```
scheme: 
user:
password:
host:
port:
path: example.com/
query:
opaque:
registry:
fragment:
parser:
```

What I eventually want is to get the domain example.com stripped of any protocol, subdomain, directories, etc.

I've looked into [domainatrix](https://github.com/pauldix/domainatrix) but it wont bundle with my project. Is there a way to do this with Ruby's `URI.parse`? Or will I have to look into other avenues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `example.com/` isn't a full URL.  URI rightly assumes it's a path.  If it were me and you're going to have a lot of these fragments I'd just brute force it.

```
 > "example.com/".sub(%r{^.*?://}, '').sub(%r{/.*$}, '')
 => "example.com"

> "http://subdomain.example.com/path/here".sub(%r{^.*?://}, '').sub(%r{/.*$}, '')
 => "subdomain.example.com"
```

Stripping the subdomain off is another ball of wax as you'd need to example the TLD to determine what is appropriate so you don't end up with say "com.uk"

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to do request.domain assuming you are doing this in a controller.

You can also use request.path and request.subdomain

For example: http://www.domain.com/users/123

```
request.subdomain => 'www'
request.domain => 'domain.com'
request.path => '/users/123'
```